# Datalogic 8500xt misses the last digit while scanning barcodes using pyserial

Tags: python, barcode-scanner, pyserial, serial-communication

I'm trying to scan barcodes using a Datalogic 8500xt scanner with pyserial in my Python program. However, I'm facing an issue where the scanner misses the last digit of the barcode. For instance, if I scan a barcode that has seven digits, such as "1234567", the scanner only returns "123456". The same issue occurs when I scan a barcode that has five digits, such as "09876", and the scanner returns "0987".

I have tried to adjust the scanner's settings to fix the issue, but with no success. I also tried to increase the sleep time between scans, but it didn't help either. I'm using pyserial to communicate with the scanner, and I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing in my code.

Here is a code snippet that I'm using to read data from the scanner:

```
 try:
        # device_port= serial_ports()[0]
        device_port= 'COM3'
        print("device_port : ",device_port)
        print("Connecting device")
        ser = serial.Serial(
            port = device_port,
            timeout = 1,
            baudrate=9600,
            parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,
        )
        i = True

        while i:
            # if wt == 'S14\x0D':
                ser.write('S01\x0D'.encode('utf-8'))
                print("connected")
                # ser.write('\x05'.encode('utf-8'))
                # time.sleep(1)
                barcode=None
                read_val = ser.read(size=128)
                read_val = str(read_val, 'UTF-8')  
                res = list(read_val)
                print(res)
                res = res[4:-1]
                if len(res)>0:
                    i=False
                    barcode=res
        ser.close()
        return {"barcode": barcode}
                
    except:           
            return {"message": "No Barcode Device Connected"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see three possible culprits:

- Off by one logic error: try `res = res[4:-1]` -> `res = res[4:]`
- Insufficient timeout time, try `timeout=1 -> timeout=5,  # Increase timeout to allow more time for data transfer`
- Insufficient read buffer size: try `ser.read(size=128)` -> `ser.read(size=256)`

Also remove the bare `except` and replace it with a more specific one, to avoid hiding errors while debugging.

Comment: done all three steps.

now i'm getting response is :-

['b', "'", '\\', 'x', 'd', '3', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '8', '\\', 'x', 'c', '1', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '4', '\\', 'x', 'b', '9', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '\\', 'x', 'b', '6', '1', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '4', '\\', 'r', '\\', 'x', 'd', '3', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '8', '\\', 'x', 'c', '1', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '4', '\\', 'x', 'b', '9', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '\\', 'x', 'b', '6', '1', '\\', 'x', 'b', '0', '4', '\\', 'r', "'"]

Comment: the barcode I scanned contained 8 in last but it is responding only 4

Comment: @jaswant Does the code run without errors when removing the try except?